# Javascript adding an additional unnecessary double quotes in string

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, jqgrid-formatter

I am having a formatter function for a jqgrid column and I am creating an anchor tag through a string inside the formatter function and calling a function inside the onclick attribute of anchor tag. I am trying to pass a javascript object as a function argument. The code of which is as under:

```
function Popupformatter(cellvalue, options, rowdata, action) {
return '<a href="#" onclick=\"ShowNotification(' + rowdata + ')\">' + rowdata.UpdateName + '</a>';
}
```

However, the above code is generating the column tag in jqgrid as under:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowNotification([object" object])") My New Notification</a>
```

I am unable to trace from where did the additional double quote(") is getting generated in the rendered html. I tried changing the double quotes to single quotes and vice-versa, still not able to find out the problem inside the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you placing `slash` berofe and after function?

Comment: The slash I am using to add an escape character, like a double quote is being added as \". If anyone has an idea about how the anchor tag we can generate through a string value, then please tell me whether I am generating the anchor tag correct or not ? How am I required to put the double quotes inside the string for anchor tag. ?

Comment: even if you succeed to pass the `rowdata` in `ShowNotification` `onclick ` is not gona work,

Comment: @ozil What is the reason behind what you said that the `onclick` wont work ? And what is the other way round for passing `rowdata` as a function argument and also making the `onclick` work as usual ?

Comment: have you been able to go so far
`function Popupformatter(cellvalue, options, rowdata, action) {
return '<a href="#" onclick="ShowNotification()">click me</a>';
}`
`function ShowNotification(){alert('hey')}`

Comment: @ozil Well I did found one solution to this. But that solution was without passing an object and passing a string data as function argument. But I wanted if I could send the whole object without openly sending the data into double quotes as a function argument. And ofcourse my onclick does works in this case, when I am passing it as string argument.

Comment: how it is possible that it is working have a look at [demo] (http://jsfiddle.net/3L05gtbx/1/)

Comment: The click does gets fired. If you look carefully inside the console, it only shows that the function is not defined i.e. somehow it is not getting that function. I made changes to your fiddle and it does fires the onclick event, have a look..[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3L05gtbx/8/)

Comment: it is different from your scenario you want some thing like this  `onclick="ShowNotification()">` nor `onclick="javascript:alert(\'Hey\')">`